# Setting cookie expiration for OpenIdConnectAuthentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, owin, openid-connect

I'm trying to set an expiration date for OIDC cookie. I tried to set `AuthenticationTicket.ExpiresUtc` in `Notifications.SecurityTokenValidated` but the `.AspNet.Cookies` cookie expiration time is still "Session" in browser. Is there a way to do this?

```cs
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType,
                CookieHttpOnly = true
            });

var oidcOptions = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                UseTokenLifetime = false,
                ..
                SignInAsAuthenticationType = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType,
                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                {
                    SecurityTokenReceived = n =>
                    {
                        n.AuthenticationTicket.Properties.ExpiresUtc = System.DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(30);
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }
            };
```

I'm using ASP.NET MVC .NET 4.5.2, Owin 4.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you also need to add `n.AuthenticationTicket.Properties.IsPersistent = true;`